# Getting Error While Using ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a View(FilerOverall) and inside the view i am calling some method using renderaction method.

```
@{
Html.RenderAction("Gettemplate", "FinancialDisclosure", 
    new { FormId = "100",ScheduleId= "10" });
};
```

and in controller i have written the action method like

```
public ActionResult Gettemplate(string FormId ,string ScheduleId)
{
    List<FDDTO> FD1 = FDService.GetScheduleDetails(100, 10).ToList();
    return View ("EditorTemplates/FDDTO", FD1);
}
```

when I executed the app I am getting this error:

> "A public action method 'Gettemplate' was not found on controller
>   'WorldBank.DOI.Presentation.Controllers.FinancialDisclosureController'."}

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Html.Action` instead of `Html.RenderAction`

```
@Html.Action("Gettemplate", "FinancialDisclosure",  new { FormId = "100",ScheduleId= "10" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I actually used editorfor and my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

Create new view like **Demo.cshtml**

now

```
public ActionResult Gettemplate(string FormId ,string ScheduleId)
{
    List<FDDTO> FD1 = FDService.GetScheduleDetails(100, 10).ToList();
    return View ("Demo", FD1);
}
```

now put in your **FilerOverall.cshtml** below code

```
@{
Html.RenderAction("Gettemplate", "FinancialDisclosure", 
    new { FormId = "100",ScheduleId= "10" });
};
```